# Is there an infinite loop in my code?

Tags: javascript

My webpage crashes when I run this:

```
function replace()
{
    var str = document.getElementById('feeds');
    var cont = str.innerHTML;
    curstring = "twitter: ";
    while (cont.indexOf(curstring))
    {
        replaced = cont.replace(curstring,"TWIMG ");
        str.innerHTML = replaced;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: You might want to check if your TAB key is working... `:p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.  You never reassign cont.  Perhaps try this?

```
function replace()
{
  var str = document.getElementById('feeds');
  var cont = str.innerHTML;
  curstring = "twitter: ";
  while (cont.indexOf(curstring) != -1)
  {
    replaced = cont.replace(curstring,"TWIMG ");
    str.innerHTML = replaced;
    cont = str.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when `curstring` is in `cont`. In your `while` loop `cont` won't be changed, so `cont.indexOf(curstring)` will always be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, yes.

Your `cont.indexOf()` test should test for `>= 0`, since on not-found that function returns -1, which evaluates *true* and will cause the loop to go around again.

It'll currently only terminate if `cont` *starts with* `curstring`.

Per other answers, you also need to overwrite `cont` inside the loop too.

```
function replace() {
  var curstring = "twitter: ";
  var str = document.getElementById('feeds');

  var cont = str.innerHTML;
  var old = cont;

  // NB: indexOf() returns -1 on failure, so you
  //     must compare against that,
  while (cont.indexOf(curstring) >= 0) {
    cont = cont.replace(curstring, "TWIMG ");
  }

  // taken outside the loop so we don't modify the DOM
  // over and over if the match is repeated - only update
  // the DOM if the string got changed
  if (cont !== old) {
    str.innerHTML = cont;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, there is no need to check for >=0 because if it returns -1 it will evaluate as false.

Comment: Yes, `>= 0 ` is correct.  But `while (a.indexOf(b)) { ... }` is not, because `-1` does _not_ evaluate as false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `cont` never changes in the loop so if `cont.indexOf(curstring)` is true it will be true forever and your program goes into an infinite loop.